401 when accessing newly created realm in Keycloak
I have an installation service so I can programmatically create a new tenant which includes setting up a Keycloak Realm.
In order to do this, I am using the Keycloak.Net.Core library and I have written the following code:
public async Task InstallKeycloakRealmAsync(string realmIdentifier, CreateOrganizationRequest createOrganizationRequest)
{
    var client = new KeycloakClient("https://auth.dronenet.ai", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DRONENET_KEYCLOAK_USERNAME"), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DRONENET_KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD"));
    var realm = new Realm
    {
        Enabled = true,
        EditUsernameAllowed = true,
        RememberMe = true,
        ResetPasswordAllowed = true,
        _Realm = realmIdentifier,
        UserManagedAccessAllowed = true
    };

    try
    {
        var succeeded = await client.ImportRealmAsync("master", realm);

        if (!succeeded)
        {
            throw new KeycloakRealmImportFailedException(realmIdentifier);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to create keycloak realm.");
        throw new KeycloakRealmImportFailedException(realmIdentifier);
    }

    try
    {
        var createUserSucceeded = await client.CreateUserAsync(realm._Realm, new User
        {
            UserName = createOrganizationRequest.Credentials.Username,
            Email = createOrganizationRequest.Credentials.Email,
            Enabled = false,
            FirstName = createOrganizationRequest.Contacts.Owner.Name.Split(" ")[0],
            LastName = createOrganizationRequest.Contacts.Owner.Name.Contains(" ")
                ? createOrganizationRequest.Contacts.Owner.Name.Split(" ")[1]
                : null,
            Credentials = new[]
            {
                new Credentials
                {
                    Type = "password",
                    Value = createOrganizationRequest.Credentials.Password,
                    Temporary = false
                }
            }
        });

        if (!createUserSucceeded)
        {
            throw new KeycloakCreateUserFailedException(realm._Realm,
                createOrganizationRequest.Credentials.Username);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to create keycloak user.");
        throw new KeycloakCreateUserFailedException(realm._Realm,
            createOrganizationRequest.Credentials.Username);
    }

    try
    {
        var createClientSucceeded = await client.CreateClientAsync(realmIdentifier, new Client
        {
            Enabled = true,
            Name = "dronenet",
            ClientId = "dronenet",
            RedirectUris = new[] {"http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:8081", "https://dronenet.ai"},
            WebOrigins = new[] {"*"}
        });

        if (!createClientSucceeded)
        {
            throw new KeycloakCreateClientFailedException(realmIdentifier);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to create keycloak client.");
        throw new KeycloakCreateClientFailedException(realmIdentifier);
    }
}

The realm is successfully created, however, the creation of the user fails with a 401 Unauthorized, which I don't except because I am authenticating with the main account that has access to all of the realms. Of course, I do believe it has to do with the fact that the scope may be insufficient through the API in comparison to when you use it through the admin UI Panel, however, I don't know how to gain access to the realm to successfully set up the user and client, as I am unable to create a new user which would have sufficient access. I fiddled around with my account settings.
Any ideas?
